# Check if mysql datetime is > 1 hour old using php

Tags: php, mysql, time

Here's the code that I have now:

```
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )){ ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row["ID"] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["LOCATION"] ?></td>
    <?php 
        if ($row["STATUS"] != "OK")
        { 
        ?><td bgcolor="red"><?php echo $row["STATUS"] ?></td><?php 
        } else{ 
        ?><td><?php echo $row["STATUS"] ?></td><?php 
        } 
        ?><td><?php echo $row["TIME"] ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

What I want to do is make another if statement similar to the one that I did for status, but highlight anything older than 1 hour as red.   I know that MySql is running in UMT and the server itself is running in EST, and didn't know if that would cause an issue either (as I suck with php).

Comment: What format is `$row['TIME']` in? Standard `DATETIME`?

Comment: Can't you use MySQL to perform this logic for you?  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: @Jack -- Yes it is.    yossarian -- I am doing a select * from table order by ID; as I need to display them all either way, I just need to highlight the ones that have bad statuses / are over an hour old.

Comment: @Damien.Bell I suspect he means something like `SELECT *,NOW()-TIME>3600 AS is_old FROM table ORDER BY ID;`

Comment: I'm not at all opposed to handling it in this fashion, however I am incredibly unsure of how to handle it on the php side (I'm a java programmer, but the server I'm working on doesn't support JSP)

Comment: @Damien.Bell it would just appear as another element in your `$row` array, so you'd just say `if $row['is_old'] ...`. See Nerdwood's answer for a better version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best way would be to use your SQL query to calculate if it's older than 1 hour, that way you have no "timezone issues".

```
SELECT *, IF(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), DateTimeField)) >= 1, 1, 0) AS OlderThanAnHour
```

Comment: Beautiful solution, bravo.

Comment: Why the timediff? Doesn't that compare only the time portion? As in, if I come back tomorrow at the same time, would it be new again? :) I could be wrong, I didn't check the manual.

Comment: `TIMEDIFF()` will calculate a time difference between 2 points in time, not just the time portion of 2 points in time... so if you had `2013-04-10 06:00:00` and `2013-04-08 18:00:00` you should get `36:00:00`.

Answer (score 1):

I love to use DateTime for such tasks because often it is more readable than some timestamp calculation. Maybe you like that approach too.

```
$inOneHour = new DateTime();
$inOneHour->modify('-1 hour');
$time = new DateTime($row['TIME']);

if ($time < $inOneHour) {
    /* your code */
}
```

Comment: This would have timezone issues though.

Answer (score 1):

If the database server is in UTC, you can compare times using `strtotime()`:

```
$now = time();

while ... {

    if (strtotime("{$row['TIME']} GMT") + 3600 < $now) {
         // it's old, dude!
    }
}
```

You could also add an expression in your query that determines the age:

```
`TIME` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) AS is_old
```

Then, in PHP:

```
if ($row['is_old']) {
    // it's old dude!
}
```

Comment: From the question:  "and the server itself is running in EST"

Comment: @Damien.Bell What the server runs in doesn't matter; I've made a small adjustment though to treat the time as utc.

Comment: @Damien.Bell Added a SQL expression as well, if you were still worried about `strtotime()` giving the wrong results :)

Comment: Although I ended up going with another answer, I want you to know that I came back to upvote this.  You've been super-helpful throughout and I appreciate that.   Hopefully I run into you again.